# In Haskell, how can I create a list with multiple types?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a task to generate a list which can contains strings and integers too. How can I solve this problem in Haskell?

Comment: Hetrogenous lists in Haskell are not possible (at least not with default lists). You can however make a list `[Either String Int]`, and then for instance use `[Left "a", Right 2, Right 4, Left "b"]`

Comment: First ask yourself why you *need* strings and integers in the same list.

Comment: chepner: I don't know :(  I got this task from my school.

Comment: Willem: It works, thank you! :)

Answer (score 7):

That would be `[Either String Integer]`.

Note this is not a list that can contain strings and integers, this is a list of "eithers" where each "either" can contain either a string or an integer (there are two levels of containment). There are various other ways to approximate "a list which can contain strings and integers" but they are not recommended

Comment: Thank you, guys! Which solution is the most recommended?

Comment: @MichielBorkent yes, and using something standard has the benefit of being standard, i.e. familiar to most programmers.

Answer (score 4):

```
data StringOrInt
  = MyString String
  | MyInt Int
  deriving (Eq, Show)

x :: [StringOrInt]
x = [MyString "a", MyInt 2]
```

Comment: Also explored `Dynamic` a bit:
https://gist.github.com/borkdude/8ef26e016824f59e526d5b31e329bcf1